# Wikimedia function to get all my Templates

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

I need to get all the pages I have created like Templates in my wikimedia webpage. I have to do this with javascript.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [UserContribs API query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Usercontribs), like this:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&list=usercontribs&ucuser=Ilmari_Karonen&ucnamespace=10&ucshow=new&continue=

Basically, the parameters you need are:

- `format=json` to get results in JSON format, which is probably what you want for JavaScript.  (I've used `jsonfm` in the example link above to get pretty-printed human readable output.)
- `action=query` to indicate that this is, indeed, a [query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query) rather than, say, an edit or a login attempt.
- `list=usercontribs` to indicate that you want a *list* of a user's *contributions* (i.e. the stuff you see on the [Special:Contributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions) page).
- `ucuser=your_username` to select which user's contributions you want to see.  (The example link above shows mine.)
- `ucnamespace=10` to select only contributions to templates.  (10 is the [namespace number](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace#Built-in_namespaces) for the built-in Template namespace).
- `ucshow=new` to select only contributions that involve creating a new page.  (Note that this also includes page moves; I don't see any simple way to filter those out.)

Of course, there are other [parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Usercontribs#Parameters) you may also want to include.

I've also included an empty `continue=` parameter to indicate that I want to use the [new query continuation syntax](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries), and to suppress the warning about it.  Obviously, if you actually want to use query continuation, you'll need to implement the client-side part yourself (or use an MW API client that implements it for you).  Here's one simplistic way to do that:

```javascript
function getNewTemplatesForUser( username ) {
    var queryURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=usercontribs&ucnamespace=10&ucshow=new';
    queryURL += '&ucuser=' + encodeURIComponent( username );

    var callback = function( json ) {
        // TODO: actually process the results here

        if ( json.continue ) {
            var continueURL = queryURL;
            for ( var attr in json.continue ) {
                continueURL += '&' + attr + '=' + encodeURIComponent( json.continue[attr] );
            }
            doAjaxRequest( continueURL, callback );
        }
    };
    doAjaxRequest( queryURL + '&continue=', callback );
}
```

Comment: I did not know I can use the API in this way, thanks a lot, very helpful answer